# same functions with different results

Tags: c, lazy-evaluation

```
char *getInput2(char *param) {
    int data_len;
    data_len=atoi(getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"));
    char input[9];
    fgets(input, 9, stdin);

    return strdup (input+6);

}
```

and

```
char *getInput2(char *param) {

    char input[9];
    fgets(input, 9, stdin);

    return strdup (input+6);

}
```

why the ouptut of above functons are different?

for example the post value is 
max_n=20

first functions output:"x_n"
second functions output:"20"

Comment: Did you already run them? What did you get? Show your effort ...

Comment: Because you gave them different inputs?

Comment: This is your forth question around the same subject within a day or two. Unfortunately the quality of the questions did not improve. What do you think the people on SO are for you?

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: i think he dont know what are talking about, .... maybe know `some C` voting to close, question incomplete. ;-d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functions is same, first `getInput2` doing something more but result of this calculations is not usable in future instructions.

But when `CONTENT_LENGHT` not exists then you `atoi` gets `NULL` and her code was stop from Debug Assertion.

```
/* validation section */
if (endptr != NULL)
{
    /* store beginning of string in endptr */
    *endptr = (char *)nptr;
}
_VALIDATE_RETURN(nptr != NULL, EINVAL, 0L);
_VALIDATE_RETURN(ibase == 0 || (2 <= ibase && ibase <= 36), EINVAL, 0L);
```

Comment: unless the `getenv` returns null (when `CONTENT_LENGTH` is not defined) and `atoi` fails (it chokes on `null`). Then the output is different because of the exception thrown (*you just see the error..*) :) ..